# updating tensor slices in a batch in tensorflow based on indexes stored in another tensor for each batch

Tags: tensorflow, slice, batch-processing, tensor, assign

Given a boolean mask tensor of shape [None,#number of timesteps] (All set to false). Also have another tensor with indexes stored for each batch. The index range is (0,#number of timesteps). Its shape is [None,1]. Using the index tensor, for each batch individually , should update a slice of the original boolean mask to True.

For example consider the mask to be [[False,False,False,False],[False,False,False,False]] and the index tensor to be [2,3]. The output should be [[True,True,False,False],[True,True,True,False]].
i.e, in first batch [:2] are set to true and in the second batch [:3] are set to true.

How to achieve the above in tensorflow without using session calls and for all batches at once?

Comment: `mask = index < tf.range(number_of_timestamps)`?

Comment: I didnt get what you were saying?

Comment: E.g., if you have `index = tf.constant([[2], [3]])` and `number_of_timesteps = 4`, then `mask = index < tf.range(number_of_timesteps)` should give the result you want. Or if you instead have `index = tf.constant([2, 3])`, then just `mask = tf.expand_dims(index, axis=1) < tf.range(number_of_timesteps)`.

Comment: Thanks what I wanted was index > tf.range(number_of_timesteps)